# Is it better to use DataTrigger instead of a databinding?

Tags: wpf, binding

If I wanted to hide(or change visibility, color, etc) of an element in WPF is it better to use DataTrigger or a binding with a converter?

Sounds like two ways to achieve the same goal. When is it better to user one over another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can tell you about my experience.

I use databinding with converters for the following cases:

1. For the `Visibility` property (there is the built-in converter in WPF).
2. In Silverlight applications (although there are silverlight-compatible data triggers in the `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` library, they are not as convenient as WPF triggers).
3. If the source object contains many possible values. Enum to image converter, for example, it is easier to write 5 if-else clauses than 5 datatriggers.

Datatriggers:

1. If I want to change several different properties at once (background, visibility, thickness).
2. For brushes (It isn't easy to create brush in C# code by using the hex-number of the color).
3. If I want to apply static resources.
4. They can be used for displaying animation and running storyboards.

Sometimes I prefer the MVVM approach: I create additional properties of the necessary type in the viewmodel so that they can be bound directly without converting.

Comment: I'd like to add that DataTriggers can start storyboards.

Comment: @Jens Yes, you are right. Although animation in data triggers is not so common.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is it depends.

Data Triggers only offer equality operations against a single data source.

If you need to have parameters or multi-value binding you would need to use a converter.

Comment: Right but then the follow up question is: What do data triggers provide that data binding doesn't?