# WPF DataTrigger vs .Net Property

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I am using MVVM pattern and have a scenario where I need to hide a control based on some functional logic.

I have two options to handle it.

1. I can create a boolean property on view model and bind this with corresponding control to handle visibility and this property gets set based on some functional logic.
2. I can use a DataTrigger on control to handle visibility on XAML itself which use same functional logic here. (This functional logic are easy to access on XAML)

Question - Which is the correct way to handle it in terms of performance and maintainability etc. in WPF?

Comment: Good question. :) I am interested to find the answers. I would be inclined to use option 1 as that is what I thought the point of the view model is. :)

Comment: @Russell: I Agree with you. No need to maintain 2 triggers. You only need to maintain 1 property. =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to use DataTrigger instead of a databinding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306983/is-it-better-to-use-datatrigger-instead-of-a-databinding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say option 1: Say u want to snap on a Silverlight View. Then you don't have to go and create the trigger in the Silverlight View.

So the first option will be the best pattern according to MVVM.

Answer (score 4):

just have a look at this

[Is it better to use DataTrigger instead of a databinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306983/is-it-better-to-use-datatrigger-instead-of-a-databinding)

Comment: That is a good link, it would be good if you could summarise it in your answer here to give more detail. :)